# Vertical 95% Confidence Interval plot 2 groups comparison

Tags: r, plot, r-forestplot

So my end goal is to have a plot with multiple 95% confidence intervals plotted vertically in 2 groups like this example:

[image: Text]

I have found this code: https://rpubs.com/nati147/703463

But how can I add groupwise comparison in the plot?

> Write a function ‘CI_95’ that takes input a vector of sample values,
> and outputs the 95% confidence interval for this sample. You can use
> the ‘margin_error_95’ function.

```
CI_95 <- function(sample_vals, sig){
  error <- margin_error_95(sample_vals, sig)
  CI <- mean(sample_vals) + c(-1, 1)*error
}
```

> Write a function called ‘margin_error_95’ that takes input a vector of
> sample values, and outputs the margin of error for a 95% confidence
> interval.

```
margin_error_95 <- function(sample_vals, sig){
  n <- length(sample_vals)
  mar_err <- 1.96*(sig/sqrt(n))
}

plot_CI_95 <- function(seed){
  B <- 100
  n <- 30
  mu <- 5
  sig <- 1.2
  
  set.seed(seed)
  # extract upper bound of CI's
  
  x_1 <- replicate(B,
                   {samp <- rnorm(n, mean = mu, sd = sig )
                   max(CI_95(samp, sig))
                   }
  )
  
  #extract lower bound of CI's
  
  set.seed(seed)
  
  x_0 <- replicate(B,
                   {samp <- rnorm(n, mean = mu, sd = sig )
                   min(CI_95(samp, sig))
                   }
  )
  
  set.seed(seed)
  
  means <- replicate(B, mean(rnorm(n, mean = mu, sd = sig)))
  
  plot(means, 1:B, pch = 20,
       xlim = c(mu - sig, mu + sig),
       ylim = c(0,B+1),
       xlab = "sample means",
       ylab = "index of the CI",
       main = paste(B, "Confidence intervals")
  )
  
  for (i in 1:B){
    if(between(mu, x_0[i], x_1[i])){
      segments(x_0[i], i, x_1[i], i, lwd = 2) #plot CI's that contain the mean in black
    } else {
      segments(x_0[i], i, x_1[i], i, col = "red", lwd = 2) #plot CI's that don't contain the mean in red
    }
  }
  
  abline(v=mu, col = "blue") #plot a vertical line at the population mean
}
```

Run plot:

```
plot_CI_95(1)
```

[image: Text]

Comment: Do you mean the male/female comparison with different bars? Or do you mean the four panels, which seem to have 2 panels per group (T1 and T2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, although it might require some further refinement based on your preferences. I kept the general structure of your `plot_CI_95` function, but added a loop over the different groups. This meant that the `mu` and `sig` variables now must have multiple values, one for each group if you are going to show group-wise differences. There are also some colors and other graphical parameters. The result is shown below.

To avoid the intervals for the two groups overlapping, there are a few parameters to tweak. 1) figure `height` in `png` (increasing value makes more space between groups, 2) `offset` parameter (can increase up to about 0.3), or 3) `lwd` in the `segments` functions (smaller values mean thinner lines). Using `png` or similar function to directly save the figure will allow fine tuning of the desired look.

[image: Example Plot with Group Differences]

```
library(dplyr)

CI_95 <- function(sample_vals, sig){
  error <- margin_error_95(sample_vals, sig)
  CI <- mean(sample_vals) + c(-1, 1)*error
}


margin_error_95 <- function(sample_vals, sig){
  n <- length(sample_vals)
  mar_err <- 1.96*(sig/sqrt(n))
}

png("group_plot.png",height=7,width=3,units = 'in',res=1000)

plot_CI_95 <- function(seed){
  B <- 100
  n <- 30
  # mean and std dev as a vector of values
  # need to have same length
  # assume one value per group
  mu <- c(5,4.5) # group1, group2
  sig <- c(1.2,1) # group1, group2
  offset<- 0.25 # controls point and line offset from nominal value
  # colors for 2 groups
  colsuse  <- c('steelblue','gold')
  
  # loop over groups
  # mu and sig are now indexed by this loop
  for(j in 1:length(mu)){
    # use seed+j to make different random sample for each group
    
    # extract upper bound of CI's
    set.seed(seed+j)
    x_1 <- replicate(B,
                     {samp <- rnorm(n, mean = mu[j], sd = sig[j])
                     max(CI_95(samp, sig[j]))
                     }
    )
    
    #extract lower bound of CI's
    set.seed(seed+j)
    x_0 <- replicate(B,
                     {samp <- rnorm(n, mean = mu[j], sd = sig[j])
                     min(CI_95(samp, sig[j]))
                     }
    )
    
    set.seed(seed+j)
    
    means <- replicate(B, mean(rnorm(n, mean = mu[j], sd = sig[j])))
    
    # for first group, establish the plot
    # for second group, add values to the plot
    # if groups are very different this might need to be modified with the xlim
    if(j == 1){
      plot(means, (1:B)+offset*ifelse(j==1,1,-1), pch = 20,
           xlim = c(mu[j] - sig[j], mu[j] + sig[j]),
           ylim = c(0,B+1),
           xlab = "sample means",
           ylab = "index of the CI",
           main = paste(B, "Confidence intervals"),
           col=colsuse[j]
      )
    }else{
      points(means, (1:B)+offset*ifelse(j==1,1,-1), pch = 20,
           col=colsuse[j])
    }
 
    for (i in 1:B){
      if(between(mu[j], x_0[i], x_1[i])){
        segments(x_0[i], i+offset*ifelse(j==1,1,-1), x_1[i], i+offset*ifelse(j==1,1,-1), col=colsuse[j], lwd = 1) #plot CI's that contain the mean in black
      } else {
        segments(x_0[i], i+offset*ifelse(j==1,1,-1), x_1[i], i+offset*ifelse(j==1,1,-1), col = "red", lwd = 1) #plot CI's that don't contain the mean in red
      }
    }
    
    abline(v=mu[j], col = colsuse[j]) #plot a vertical line at the population mean
  }
  
  par(xpd=F)
  # legend for the groups
  legend("topright",legend = c('Male','Female'),lty=1,col=colsuse,cex=0.5)
}

plot_CI_95(1)

dev.off()
```

Comment: Yjx!...but is there a way to have not overlap them?

Comment: @H.berg, I added some explanation of how to fix overlapping lines and modified the code example. One can stretch the figure vertically (when exporting or using `png()` or similar functions), plot thinner lines (`lwd` in `segment`), or change the `offset` parameter. It will probably require adjusting a couple of these options based on your desired final figure shape, size, and line thickness.